# Cout of a string is giving an error and a hard time some insight help pls?

Tags: c++, string, cout, cin

I cant find the error in this piece of code could anyone please insight me? I ran the debugging but the errors are un-understandable..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  string name; 
  cout << "Input your name please?" << endl; 
  cin >> name; 

  if
      {
          (name == "Bart Simpson")  
    cout << "You have been very naughty" << endl; 
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that your actual code, or did you make a mistake when posting?

Comment: In the future, actually _post_ your errors, don't just mention that you got some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

1. You have some missing `#include`s, which probably caused your *initial* compiler errors.
2. You have a simple syntax error with your `if` statement.
3. Using the stream extraction operator will never yield a string with whitespace inside of it.

The following should work as you expect:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input your name please?" << endl;

    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name == "Bart Simpson")
    {
        cout << "You have been very naughty" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(You need to include `string` for `std::string` and `std::getline`, and `ostream` for `std::endl`.)

Comment: Except `name` can never be `Bart Simpson`

Comment: @JohnDibling why cant the name ever be Bart Simpson? (I tried it and indeed I got an error but when I tried Bart it worked)

Comment: @Sinner : The stream extraction operator (`operator>>` in this context) stops extraction as soon as it encounters whitespace or EOF, so you can't use it to extract a string with a space inside. Use `std::getline` instead.

Answer (score 3):

*I assume the bracket in the wrong place is just a problem when pasting the code*

> if(name == "Bart Simpson")

`name` will never equal `"Bart Simpson"`, since extracting a `string` stops when it encounters whitespace; so it would only be `"Bart"`. Perhaps you want to use `getline()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
if (name == "Bart Simpson")
{
    cout << "You have been very naughty" << endl;
}
```

And you need to include `<string>`